# How to make sum of column value ? in parse

Tags: parse-platform

I just wanted to know is there a feature in parse to get the **SUM of the column value**. I read in the link https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-make-sum-of-column-value that this feature is not supported through query we need to use cloud code. Is this the same till now? Any updates on this?

Comment: Yup. Still the same. Parse started doing a AMA every month. You can request it as a feature through a normal portal or exercise your concerns in Julys APA